# Replace text inside CDATA tag in SOAP Body using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to be able to replace some text inside the CDATA tag of a soap body using XSLT

The XML is below

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <Response>
         <result xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Extract authenticated="0"><ErrorList><Error>1</Error></ErrorList></Extract>]]></result>
      </Response>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I want to be able to replace the data inside the CDATA tag removing the XML declaration version and adding a new tag to both the beginning and end called

> "Extract main"

```
<ExtractMain><Extract authenticated="0"><ErrorList><Error>1</Error></ErrorList></Extract></ExtractMain>
```

I was starting to try something below but im not familar with XSLT and this seems quite complex to me

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Extract']">
        // what do i do?
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **[1]** There are no tags inside a CDATA section. **[2]** CDATA-Blocks are kind of text nodes, so you are dealing with string only! **[3]** You might go with some vendor implementations like `saxon:parse` or similar. XSLT 3 might offer you a `parse(string)` function as well. **[4]** This is not the first topic about processing CDATA, try a search on SO.

Comment: Here is what you should do: Change the server side so that it produces a sane response. If that's not possible, you must parse the response XML, select the string value of `//Response/result`, parse that as XML into a second document and then work with that document.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot change server side. I can extract the text inside the result with xpath then use this as a param within my new xslt but i have no knowledge of how to achieve what I want to do.